# Error handling in perl

Tags: perl, exception

I have run.pl  and decrypt.pm

run.pl :

```
my $secret2 = "test password";
my $ret=decrypt::decodeIt($secret2);
print $ret;
```

decrypt.pm :

```
sub decodeIt {
$tmp="";
.........
.........
.........
return $tmp
}
```

I am calling decodeIt() sub in run.pl. But something goes wrong in decodeIt sub and run.pl throws errors. I dont want to see these error exception to be printed it the screen and i want to catch the error in run.pl and do something else if there is an error like below. I tried like below but couldnt catch error.

```
if(!decrypt::decodeIt($secret2)){
print "Error in decode";
} else {
my $ret=decrypt::decodeIt($secret2);
print "No Error :".$ret;
}
```

Now the errors i see in screen are;

```
Argument "te" isn't numeric in int at decrypt.pm line 61.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 's' ignored at decrypt.pm line 64.
Illegal hexadecimal digit ' ' ignored at decrypt.pm line 64.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 's' ignored at decrypt.pm line 64.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 's' ignored at decrypt.pm line 64.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'o' ignored at decrypt.pm line 64.
substr outside of string at decrypt.pm line 68.
Use of uninitialized value $string in length at decrypt.pm line 69.
```

I don't want to see these errors on screen. I just want to understand if there is an error and do some action if there is an error.

Comment: The error is in `decrypt.pm`. On line 61. We need to see what's on line 61-70 to be able to answer.

Comment: I dont want to prevent error. It is ok to have error. I create error on purpose in subroutine in decrypt.pm. I just want to handle the error in run.pl where i call the subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the
[*block version* of `eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)
to handle exceptions

However, most of the messages you are seeing are *warnings*, which aren't trapped by `eval`, and need to be escalated to fatal errors if you want to trap them

In this code, `use warnings 'FATAL'` will make every warning fatal for the duration of the current lexical context. The `eval` block will return `undef` if there is a fatal error, otherwise it will return the value of the `decrypt::decodeIt` call

I'm not very happy about masking the error message altogether. All you will be told is that there was a problem, without any indication of what it was. I think you should reconsider this

```
my $ret = eval {
    use warnings 'FATAL';
    decrypt::decodeIt($secret2);
};

if ( defined $ret ) {
    print "No Error: $ret\n";
}
else {
    print "Error in decode\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin,Thanks for the answer. The problem is. $ret is always defined. the sub always returns $ret with some info. If there is error, it prints the error to screen. And says no error as $ret is filled with some info.

Comment: @ivbtar Please read: [mcve]. After you should [edit] your question.

Comment: @ivbtar: Please at least try my solution. `$ret` will be `undef` if there was any exception.

Comment: my $secret2 = "28EDEFHRYD73SHD84DW43DSDSDM43UYRY34";
my $rett = eval {
    use warnings 'FATAL';
    decrypt::decodeIt($secret2);
};

if ( defined $rett ) {
    print "No Error: $rett\n";
}
else {
    print "Error in decode\n";
}

Comment: You can trap warnings without making them fatal by using a signal handler for warn: `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {my $warning = shift; ...};`

Comment: @ivbtar: You need to show an example that I can run to see the same symptoms. I've tried to imagine anything that you may be doing, and all of my tests are fine.

Comment: @stevieb: Yes you can, but you would want to use `local $SIG{__WARN__} = ...` within a block, and that removes all possibility of retrieving the warning message. At least, if warnings are made fatal, the message is (probably) still in `$@`.  I didn't completely buy into the OP's request to hide *all* diagnostics!